# How to add validation. in input field in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

could you please tell me how to add validation. in input field in angular js ? Actually I am making a form which is generated by **json** .I already add validation of required .if user **submitted blank** value it show **"red border"** .But I need more validation like

1. User will not enter **"digits"** or (123) in user name and last name
2. User will not enter invalid value example **"test" ,"abc"**.These two are invalid values.if user enter these value form should be invalid .

can I add custom validation in fields

http://plnkr.co/edit/YmIMEGHm7E48wZQT9ZSb?p=preview

```
$scope.isSubmitClicked = false;

$scope.myform =''
  $scope.c ={
  "ABC": {
    "type": "LABEL",
    "editable": false
  },
  "Title": {
    "value": "Ms",
    "type": "FIELD",
    "editable": false,
    "dataType": "",
    "required":false
  },
  "First Name": {
    "value": "",
    "type": "FIELD",
    "editable": true,
    "dataType": "",
     "required":true
  },
  "Middle Name": {
    "value": "",
    "type": "FIELD",
    "editable": true,
    "dataType": "",
    "required":false
  },
   "Last Name": {
    "value": "",
    "type": "FIELD",
    "editable": true,
    "dataType": "",
    "required":true
  }
}

   $scope.submit = function ($event) {
        $scope.isSubmitClicked = true;


    };
```

Comment: Use directives to validate the form. Custom validation in directive will be live.

Comment: how ? please suggest me how

Comment: make an attribute based directive with `require: 'ngModel'`, and link it with controller: `link: function (s, e, a, ctrl) {`, then your custom validation will go into `ctrl.$validators.myValidation = function(modelValue, viewValue){...}`. Its job is to return `true` or `false` if something is valid or not. The error will show up in `myform[inputName].$error.myValidation`

Comment: can you please add this my punker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a **custom directive** for live validation on input fields.It will give valid and invalid **CSS class** to the input field based on your condition to change the error alert style, e.g you can make your border red when field is invalid.

Assuming you know how to **style** moving to next part:

```
<input  ng-required="true" ng-model="modelName" type="text" abc="modelName">
```

and your directive will be written as:

```
App.directive("abc", function() {
return {
    require: "ngModel",
    //name your scope key and value.
    scope: {
        abc: "=abc"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, modelVal) {

        modelVal.$validators.abc= function(val) {
            //Write your logic or condition in this function
           //return false if invalid and return true if valid.
            /*
            if(condition)
            {
                //if true
                reutrn true;
            }
            else{
                //if false
                return false
            }
            */
        };

        scope.$watch("abc", function() {
            modelVal.$validate();
        });

    }

};
});
```

and if you want that your form won't **submit** if any field is invalid then your form tag will become like this :

```
   <form ng-submit="myForm.$valid && submitFunction()" name="myForm">
```

remember to give **name** to your **form** and use that name to **validate** the whole form.

Here is the controller you asked for @joy:

```
  var app = angular.module('plunker', ['angularMoment', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, moment) {

 $scope.isEditableMode = true;
 $scope.isSubmitClicked = false;

$scope.myform =''
   $scope.c ={
  "ABC": {
"type": "LABEL",
"editable": false
 },
"Title": {
"value": "Ms",
"type": "FIELD",
"editable": false,
"dataType": "",
"required":false
 },
 "First Name": {
"value": "",
"type": "FIELD",
"editable": true,
"dataType": "",
 "required":true
 },
"Middle Name": {
 "value": "",
 "type": "FIELD",
 "editable": true,
 "dataType": "",
 "required":false
 },
"Last Name": {
 "value": "",
 "type": "FIELD",
 "editable": true,
 "dataType": "",
  "required":true
 }
 }

   $scope.submit = function ($event) {
    $scope.isSubmitClicked = true;


 };

 });

 app.directive("checkInput", function() {
  return {
 require: "ngModel",
 //name your scope key and value.

 link: function(scope, element, attributes, modelVal) {

    modelVal.$validators.checkInput= function(val) {
       var numberRegex= /^[0-9]+$/;
       if (val.match(numberRegex))
       {
      return false
       }
       else{
         return true
       }
  
        console.log(val);

    };

    scope.$watch("val", function() {
        modelVal.$validate();
    });

}

};
});
```

your html input element:

```
 <input type="text" name="{{key}}" class="form-control" ng-model="value.value" ng-required="value.required && isSubmitClicked" check-input>
```

Comment: thanks for help can you please add this in my plunker pls ..give one example that user only add number in use name field

Comment: Use **regex** to match the expression or use key code to see the char code, and if its a number then use `event.preventdefault()` this will prevent user from entering entering that element. I can assume now, you will be able to come up with the logic according to your problem. Any confusion let me know.

Comment: could you please help me in plunker pls

Comment: it will good for me if you add your answer in my plunker and add your directive there

Comment: @Joy you can change the regex as your validation varies. If its the solution then accept the answer thanks.